# Jpa unidirectional relation in the parent entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I want to make unidirectional relation in the parent entity, Child entities have FK from the parent entity.

```
class Person {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    String id;


    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "person_id")
    Name name;
}

class Name {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "person_id")
    String personId;

    String name;
}
```

The Name table has FK from the person table. But I just want to define the relation in person entity only.
I used  @JoinColumn for mapping and  set name as `id` from the person table

In the next example, I have one to many relations
for example

```
class Parent {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    String id;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    List<Child> childs;
    // fields...
}

class Child {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Id")
    String id;


    @Column(name = "parent_id)
          String parentId;
}
```

In one to many relation in the @JoinColumn, I set name from the child table, and reference column from the Parent table. But when I defined the same unidirectional relation in the above person class with @OneToOne I have to set the @joincolumn name from the Person table and not from the Name table.

My question is why the defining name in these two join conditions are different, In one I have to set the name as the name of the PK column name from the same table, and in the second example, I have to set the name of the column from the child table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that join column can be present only on `ToOne` side. As it's stated in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html):

> **public abstract java.lang.String name**
>
> (Optional) The name of the foreign key column. *The table in which it is found depends upon the context.*
>
> - *If the join is for a OneToOne or ManyToOne mapping using a foreign key mapping strategy, the foreign key column is in the table of the source entity or embeddable.*
> - *If the join is for a unidirectional OneToMany mapping using a foreign key mapping strategy, the foreign key is in the table of the target entity.*
> - If the join is for a ManyToMany mapping or for a OneToOne or bidirectional ManyToOne/OneToMany mapping using a join table, the foreign key is in a join table.
> - If the join is for an element collection, the foreign key is in a collection table.

Please note that the ability to use unidirectional `@OneToMany` with `@JoinColumn` was added only in [JPA 2.0](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/What_is_new_in_JPA_2.0%3F)

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
List<Child> childs;
```

When you use unidirectional `@OneToMany` without `@JoinColumn`:

```java
@OneToMany
List<Child> childs;
```

hibernate, for example, resorts to using a link table between the two joining entities.

Comment: I understand that, But my confusion is, In OneTOne mapping @Joincolumn I have to use the name of the column `id` instead of `persion_id` unlike to the second example.

Comment: A unidirectional `@OneToOne` association follows the relational database 
foreign key semantics, the parent-side owning the relationship. Since `@JoinColumn`
refers to the column name from the parent entity column name. But foreign key for `@OneToMany` association is present on the child side, so `@JoinColumn` refers to the column name of this child entity.